# Beego - Annotation routing - Are there extra steps?

Tags: beego

I'm using Beego and I don't think the annotation routing works as documented.

My router.go looks like this:

```
package routers

import (
    beego "github.com/beego/beego/v2/server/web"
    "project/controllers"
)

func init() {
    beego.Include(&controllers.InventoryController{})
}
```

I have confirmed that the router is being initialized (I import it in `main.go`).

And the controller looks like this:

```
package controllers

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    beego "github.com/beego/beego/v2/server/web"
)

type InventoryController struct {
    beego.Controller
}

func (c *InventoryController) URLMapping() {
    c.Mapping("Index", c.Index)
}

// @router /index [get]
func (c *InventoryController) Index() {
    var accountId string
    accountId = fmt.Sprintf("%s", c.Ctx.Input.GetData("account_id"))
    // do stuff
    c.Data["json"] = map[string]interface{}{"accountId": accountId}
    c.ServeJSON()
}
```

When I visit `GET /index` I receive a `404` error.

Is there some sort of generation step that I need to take?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I was using the current version.  I eventually gave up and abandoned Beego in favour of using Gorilla and Gorm

Comment: Yeah, documentation is pretty bad, I'm playing with Beego but I'm almost giving up too